# How to test data using PHP unit and Symfony Command

Tags: php, symfony, command, phpunit

I'm trying to write a test class that tests when data is updated using the command in Symfony. But I don't know how to write a functional test. I need to know, which functions to write in the class `UpdateTrackedContainerCommandTest`, so that data was updated. In the documentation from Symfony I have not found any examples of it. Please, is there someone, who can give me some advice? I much appreciate any help.

Here is a command class in Symfony, that updates data through the command console:

```
#[AsCommand(
    name: 'app:update-data',
    description: 'Updating data',
    hidden: false
)]
class UpdateDataCommand extends Command
{
    private $repository;
    private $apiService;
    private $dbManager;

    public function __construct(
        Repository $repository,
        ApiService $apiService,
        DbManager $dbManager
    ) {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->apiService = $apiService;
        $this->dbManager = $dbManager;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this
            ->setHelp('This command allows you to update data...')
            ->setDescription('Updating data');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $repositoryData = $this->repository->findAll();
        $isUpdatedData = false;

        foreach ($repositoryData as $dataRow) {
            $apiData = $this->apiService->getApiData($dataRow->getReference())['result'] ?? null;

            if ($apiData) {
                foreach ($apiData['result'] as $key => $row) {
                    if ($row['id'] == $dataRow['id']) {
                        $dataRow[$key] = $row[$key];
                        $this->dbManager->persist($dataRow);
                        $isUpdatedData = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($isUpdatedData) {
            $this->dbManager->flush();
        }

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Here is a test class in Symfony, that tests with PHP unit, that data was updated as expected:

```
class UpdateTrackedContainerCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testExecute(): CommandTester
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();
        $application = new Application($kernel);

        $command = $application->find('app:update-tracked-container');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute([]);

        $commandTester->assertCommandIsSuccessful();

        return $commandTester;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be outlined first of all in the Symfony documentation, have you consulted it? According to your question this is not entirely clear, so please [edit] and elaborate. Additionally there is a lot of existing Q&A material on site about the topic and it would be helpful if you could outline which of them you have already consulted and why it didn't work out for the specific question of yours regardless.

Comment: @hakre In the Symfony documentation, there is not a lot of information about testing commands to be outlined first, unfortunately. And here on the page Stack Overflow I've also searched for additional questions but I have not found any results.

Comment: This may be true, however from top of my head I'm under the impression that at least the CommandTester is documented. Perhaps this is because your question is a bit broad and by that prone to being not clearly received what your issue is? What did not work with your functional test to execute the command? Please elaborate by [edit].

Comment: @hakre I edited this post. Is that enough explained?

Comment: So you're looking forward to test your database works? That's not a functional test (just in my book, I'm asking for clarification), traditionally db-unit was in use but nowadays it is not considered useful any longer to write such tests (general speaking, every project is different thought). At the end of the day it works asserting a value (like the command tester asserts an exist status code of zero), please see _Assertions_ and _Fixtures_ in the documentation of the testing framework you're using.